# Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Tags: android-studio, nativescript

I begin new project with NativeScript, but after more and more try i couldn't fix my error.

After  build my application with:

```
tns run android --device Pixel_4_API_30
```

i have this error :

```
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.**
```

...............................................................................................

**My trace loge :**

```
#############################################################################
   WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING

   Debug level logging will leak security sensitive information!

   https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/logging.html#sec:debug_security
#############################################################################

Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
Will send the following information to Google Analytics: {
  type: 'googleAnalyticsData',
  category: 'CLI',
  googleAnalyticsDataType: 'event',
  action: 'Performance',
  label: 'AndroidProjectService__buildProject',
  customDimensions: { cd2: 'Angular', cd9: 'false', cd5: 'CLI' },
  value: 3529
}
Error: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1
    at Errors.failWithOptions (C:\Users\BRYAN\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:157:27)
    at Errors.fail (C:\Users\BRYAN\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\nativescript\lib\common\errors.js:130:21)
    at GradleCommandService.<anonymous> (C:\Users\BRYAN\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\android\gradle-command-service.js:40:30)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (C:\Users\BRYAN\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.13.0\node_modules\nativescript\lib\services\android\gradle-command-service.js:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

tns info :

```
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 7.2.0 version and is up to date.
‼ Update available for component @nativescript/core. Your current version is 7.1.4 and the latest available version is 7.3.0.
√ Component @nativescript/ios has 7.2.0 version and is up to date.
√ Component @nativescript/android has 7.0.1 version and is up to date.
```

Answer (score -1):

Gradle is connected to Java so check your installed version is 8. If not then get the correct version and try again. `ns doctor` is your friend!

If that doesn't work, stop any java and emulator (android/qemu) related tasks/processes and try again.

If that fails try rebooting your computer and test again.